# How to serialize to include field names?

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

I'm working with another engineer to has defined a proto definition:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
package RemoteDOutCommandConfig;

message RemoteDOutCommand
{
    google.protobuf.UInt32Value command_id = 1; //transaction ID
    google.protobuf.BoolValue command_value = 2;
    uint32 command_trigger_time_utc = 3;
    google.protobuf.UInt32Value acceptable_execution_latency_secs = 4;
    google.protobuf.BoolValue disable_latency_check = 5;
}

message RemoteDOutCommandResponse
{
    enum CommandStatus
    {
        SUCCESS = 0;
        DOUT_NOT_ALLOCATED_FOR_EandT = 1;
        COMMAND_EXPIRED = 2;
        INVALID_ONBOARD_TIME = 3;
        FAILURE = 4; 
        DEVICE_KEY_OFF = 5; 
    }

    google.protobuf.UInt32Value command_id = 1;
    CommandStatus status = 2;
    uint32 command_ack_utc = 3;
}
```

One of his examples he provided was as follows:
0a 02 08 0c 12 20 18 ce bc ce af ce bd c2 9e 06 22 03 08 ce 98 01 2a 02 08 01

and when I plug that into a file and decide using protoc:

```
protoc --decode RemoteDOutCommandConfig.RemoteDOutCommand RemoteDOutCommand.proto < DOutRequest.cfg
command_id {
  value: 12
}
command_value {
}
command_trigger_time_utc: 1675325420
acceptable_execution_latency_secs {
  value: 200
}
disable_latency_check {
  value: true
}
```

So in .NET 6, I defined my class as follows:

```
 public partial class RemoteDOutCommand //: global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
    {
        //private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension __pbn__extensionData;
        //global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
         //   => global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref __pbn__extensionData, createIfMissing);

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, Name = @"command_id")]
        //[global::ProtoBuf.NullWrappedValue]
        
        public uint? CommandId { get; set; }

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2, Name = @"command_value")]
        //[global::ProtoBuf.NullWrappedValue]
        public bool? CommandValue { get; set; }

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(3, Name = @"command_trigger_time_utc")]
        public uint CommandTriggerTimeUtc { get; set; }

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(4, Name = @"acceptable_execution_latency_secs")]
        //[global::ProtoBuf.NullWrappedValue]
        public uint? AcceptableExecutionLatencySecs { get; set; }

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(5, Name = @"disable_latency_check")]
        //[global::ProtoBuf.NullWrappedValue]
        public bool? DisableLatencyCheck { get; set; }

    }
```

then creating an object:

```
RemoteDOutCommand doutProto = new RemoteDOutCommand()
            {
                CommandId = (uint?)99,
                CommandValue = (bool?)true,
                CommandTriggerTimeUtc = (uint)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds,
                AcceptableExecutionLatencySecs = (uint?)901,
                DisableLatencyCheck = (bool?)false
            };
```

When I serialize this object with an extension method I made:
(FYI: Serializer is the Protobuf.Serializer) (Version 3.22.0)

```
public static byte[] ToProtoByteArray(this Object b)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, b);
                var byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
                return byteArray;
            }
        }
```

I get the following bytes: 08 63 10 01 18 93 BE DE 9F 06 20 85 07 28 00
and decoding using protoc:

```
protoc --decode RemoteDOutCommandConfig.RemoteDOutCommand RemoteDOutCommand.proto < RemoteDoutCommandWithNamesV5.dat
command_trigger_time_utc: 1677172499
1: 99
2: 1
4: 901
5: 0
```

Overall my question is, how can I use protobuf-net to include the member names when serializing?
My terminology on proto is lacking, so I hope this makes sense.  Mine 15 bytes vs his of 26 bytes.
How do I get the same results he's expecting?

I've tried adding various items to the ProtoContract attribute, and ProtoMember attributes with no luck.  I've tried extensive searches on google, but due to my lack of terminology I'm afraid I came up empty on what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Protobuf binary wire format just *doesn't* include the names. The names from your initial example are provided by RemoteDOutCommand.proto. I suspect the problem is that the bytes you're writing out aren't *really* a representation of a RemoteDOutCommandConfig.RemoteDOutCommand

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thanks for the clarification.  I agree with your assessment then.  I just don't know yet what needs to change.

Comment: Hmm... I suspect the problem is with the use of the wrapper types. I don't know enough about protobuf-net to know how you should be annotating your code to use the built-in wrapper types, but my *suspicion* is that it's not happening at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet - you were spot on.  
Found this: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/issues/722
apparently protobuf-net doesn't support WellKnownTypes.  I had originally set my class up that way and ran into the exception and moved away from it.

Below in the comments, a user provided a work around to map the known types before serialization is done.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this and finds it helpful here is the solution I implemented:

based on comments here: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/issues/722
a user submitted by the name of: ArnaudDebaene provided a work around:

So I added that workaround to my extension method as follows:

```
public static byte[] ToProtoByteArray(this Object b)
    {
        //Protobuf-net doesn't support wellknown types
        //So if the .proto file contains: google.protobuf.UInt32Value <blah>
        //we have to add these types to the serializer before any serialization is done.
        //However they can only be added once.  So calling this extension method more than once will trigger an exception.
        //We'll catch it and ignore it.
        try
        {
            ValueMember[] fields = null;

            var typeModel = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
            fields = typeModel[typeof(Int32Value)].GetFields();
            if (fields.Count() == 0)
            {
                typeModel.Add<Int32Value>();
                typeModel[typeof(Int32Value)].AddField(1, nameof(Int32Value.Value));
            }

            fields = typeModel[typeof(UInt32Value)].GetFields();
            if (fields.Count() == 0)
            {
                typeModel.Add<UInt32Value>();
                typeModel[typeof(UInt32Value)].AddField(1, nameof(UInt32Value.Value));
            }

            fields = typeModel[typeof(Int64Value)].GetFields();
            if (fields.Count() == 0)
            {
                typeModel.Add<Int64Value>();
                typeModel[typeof(Int64Value)].AddField(1, nameof(Int64Value.Value));
            }

            fields = typeModel[typeof(UInt64Value)].GetFields();
            if (fields.Count() == 0)
            {
                typeModel.Add<UInt64Value>();
                typeModel[typeof(UInt64Value)].AddField(1, nameof(UInt64Value.Value));
            }

            fields = typeModel[typeof(DoubleValue)].GetFields();
            if (fields.Count() == 0)
            {
                typeModel.Add<DoubleValue>();
                typeModel[typeof(DoubleValue)].AddField(1, nameof(DoubleValue.Value));
            }

            fields = typeModel[typeof(FloatValue)].GetFields();
            if (fields.Count() == 0)
            {
                typeModel.Add<FloatValue>();
                typeModel[typeof(FloatValue)].AddField(1, nameof(FloatValue.Value));
            }

            fields = typeModel[typeof(BoolValue)].GetFields();
            if (fields.Count() == 0)
            {
                typeModel.Add<BoolValue>();
                typeModel[typeof(BoolValue)].AddField(1, nameof(BoolValue.Value));
            }

            fields = typeModel[typeof(StringValue)].GetFields();
            if (fields.Count() == 0)
            {
                typeModel.Add<StringValue>();
                typeModel[typeof(StringValue)].AddField(1, nameof(StringValue.Value));
            }

            fields = typeModel[typeof(BytesValue)].GetFields();
            if (fields.Count() == 0)
            {
                typeModel.Add<BytesValue>();
                typeModel[typeof(BytesValue)].AddField(1, nameof(BytesValue.Value));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //this is a hack, but it works!
        }
        
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, b);
            var byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
            return byteArray;
        }
    }
```